# No converter found for return value of type though having proper get set method

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am getting this below error. Even though i am having proper get set method in the POJO.

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No converter found for return value of type: class com.example.demo.entities.Department
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:187) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]

**pom.xml**

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.8.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

**POJO:**

```
package com.example.demo.entities;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name="departments")
public class Department  {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name="DEPT_NO")
private Long id;

@Column(name="DEPT_NAME")
private String name;

public Department() {
}

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}



}
```

**Controler**

```
@GetMapping("/departments/{id}")
public ResponseEntity<Department> getDepartmentById(@PathVariable(value = "id") Long departmentId) {
    Department department = departmentRepository.findOne(departmentId);
    if(department == null) {
        return ResponseEntity.notFound().build();
    } else {
        System.out.println("name is" + department.getName());
    }
    return ResponseEntity.ok().body(department);
}
```

Not sure, what cause this though i am having proper get set method.

Please help on this.

Comment: As I have given  mvn clean install from the Command line,  I have got below  warning.  After I removed the jar from the particular location and mvn clean install, it started to work.                                                                                  [WARNING] error reading C:\Users\Lenovo\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-core\2.8.10\jackson-core-2.8.10.jar; invalid LOC header (bad signature)
[

Answer (score 0):

you need to add Jackson dependency to your pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.0</version>
</dependency>
```

if you are not using `@RestController` annotation for controller, you need to add `@ResponseBody` annotation to your `@GetMapping` method.

```
@ResponseBody
@GetMapping("/departments/{id}")
```

Comment: jackson-databind-2.8.10.jar is in the classpath which is added by spring-boot maven dependency.                                                                                                              Controller class is annotated with @RestContoller